# MailMessage is not working even with system.net.mail reference

Tags: c#, asp.net

MailMessage is not working i don't know what I'm missing. Pls correct my program if there is missing codes or did i use wrong namespace?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web.Mail;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

protected void btnsend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      SmtpClient smtp=new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com",587);
      smtp.EnableSsl = true;
      smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
      smtp.Credentials=new NetworkCredential(txtemail.Text,txtpassword.Text);
      MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(txtemail.Text, ddlemail.Text, txtsubject.Text, txtbody.Text);
      smtp.Send(mail);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
   }
}
```

Comment: Any exception you are getting.?

Comment: i can't run the form because of MailMessage.

Error 11 'MailMessage' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Web.Mail.MailMessage' and 'System.Net.Mail.MailMessage'

Comment: then remove using System.Web.Mail; reference

Comment: ohh i solve the problem hahah LOL

Comment: Or fully qualify the name `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` everywhere you use it, if the reference to System.Web is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because you have referenced

```
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web.Mail;
```

So there was ambiguous reference between `System.Web.Mail.MailMessage` and `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage`

Remove `using System.Web.Mail;` reference